# Build failure during 'yesod devel'

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

I am following the [Yesod quick start guide](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) and I am getting errors doing `cabal install`and `yesod devel` regarding the `persistent-sqlite` module. I've already installed ghc-7.4.1 and haskell-platform-2012.2.0.0.

$ cabal install:

> Loading package persistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2 ... linking ... ghc:
>   /home/roberto/.cabal/lib/persistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2/ghc-7.4.1/HSpersistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2.o:
>   **unknown symbol `__warn_memset_zero_len'**
>
> **ghc: unable to load package `persistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2'**
>
> cabal: Error: some packages failed to install: mate-0.0.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was: ExitFailure 1

$ yesod devel:

> ghc: /home/roberto/.cabal/lib/persistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2/ghc-7.4.1/HSpersistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2.o: unknown symbol `__warn_memset_zero_len'
>
> ghc: unable to load package `persistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2' Build failure, pausing...

$ ghc-pkg list:

```
persistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2
yesod-platform-1.0.5
```

$ cabal install persistent-sqlite --reinstall

> In function ‘memset’,
>
> ```
> inlined from ‘exprDup’ at cbits/sqlite3.c:68471:0:
> ```
>
> /usr/include/bits/string3.h:82:0:
>        warning: call to ‘__warn_memset_zero_len’ declared with attribute warning: memset used with constant zero length parameter; this could
>   be due to transposed parameters

If I comment that line out, `__warn_memset_zero_len();` in `/usr/include/bits/string3.h:82`, everything goes fine. Is there a proper solution, like telling ghc not to stop on a compilation warning?

Comment: I've had a look at the .cabal file for the persistent-sqlite package at $HOME/.cabal/packages, looking for a `-Werror` ghc-option that should be causing the problem, but I found a `-Wall` instead. And the same for the yesod project I'm creating, called `mate`; mate.cabal didn't have any `-Werror`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was asking the same question on FreeNode irc on #ghc-dev and was told that this error happens due to some problems in Template Haskell mechanism that uses GHCi to pre-compile things. This happens exactly when trying to pre-compile SQLite libraries.

And I was also informed that this should be fixed with the new version of GHC that is about to be released: v7.8.x (but it will still take some time to get it as part of a new Haskell Platform).

And I am quite surprised that the problem is there for such a long time.

Comment: Thanks. Closing this question as it is being opened for quite a while now. This answer seems quite fair to me.

Answer (score 2):

Unknown symbol errors when running `yesod devel` are often the result of failing to include a module in `exposed-modules` or `other-modules` in your application's cabal file.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments that may help:

A [memset](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/memset.3.html) error with zero length is not something to ignore.

An unknown symbol error may say that the underlying sqlite library version is too old.

- Consider updating sqlite, or in case of optimization problems check if the gcc version is not too old.
- Instead of using cabal, [cabal-dev](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-dev) provides a sanboxed library database for your project.
- Instead of installing libraries separately, it's better to list them all in a .cabal project file specifying version dependencies. (the yesod-platform and the persistent-sqlite have dependencies in common)

Cheers!